# How to charge different $ amounts for different time (delivery) intervals?

Tags: extensions, ce-1.9.1.0, third-party-module, calendar, delivery-time

```
Magento 1.9.1
Amasty Delivery Date extension
```

I have the [Delivery Date extension](https://amasty.com/delivery-date.html) from Amasty

( https://amasty.com/media/user_guides/delivery_date_user_guide.pdf )

It allows me to setup different time intervals (for example 8 a.m. - noon) for delivery. I would like to charge for this - something like:

```
before 10 a.m. = $10
before noon = $7
same day afternoon = $5
```

I can set the time intervals no problem but how to change the code in order to assign the dollar value to the time interval and add it to the shopping cart total? I will have a friend help me with this but he is not familiar with Magento and I hope to get some info to point him in the right direction.

---

Updated January 15th, 2018:

**I am looking for any which way to accomplish this. It doesn't necessarily have to be through the delivery date extension from Amasty. Just to be able to setup delivery time intervals and charge for them when the customer selects this. Paying for a custom solution is not an option for us.**

Comment: Contact extension provider if they can do for you, otherwise if you offer 1k bounty then also no one is able to answer this question

Comment: add new total field (refer : http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/ ) and add select list in shipping method template file of one page checkout and in controller get that selected field and set according charge in new field

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many shipping options you need to provide, you may be able to use something like [this flat rate shipping extension](https://github.com/magespecialist/MSP_FlatShipping5) which adds 5 extra options to your `shipping methods` area with customizable cost, country filters, and custom HTML areas.

I have a similar extension on my site from a different developer, but can't find the original files or site - it may have been listed on the old Connect store.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is obviously not built to accomodate your needs. There's no way to allow the time intervals to set your shopping-cart total. I suggest you to search an appropriate alternative that can actually do this, since modifying extensions for someone who's totally not familiar with Magento can be a real pain in the ass.

A bit of research before buying these kind of extensions really is necessary, especially when you're a merchant who is'nt capable of modifying them.

Comment: I looked at many different Delivery Date extensions. Some don't even work correctly. Other's don't have all the basic features such as blocking out days when on vacation, same day delivery cut-off time.....I believe there are NO extenstions out there that would allow to setup time intervals and charge for them. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: When there's no other extension available that has these options, then unfortunately it has to be custom made. The only thing that really has to be created is a shipping method that can handle this. I would suggest you to get a quote on a development business that can help you build this, since developing it without having the capabilities to do this, would be quite difficult.